# Jetpack compose how to reduce amount of arguments in a Composable function (clean-code)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, clean-architecture

In my application I've hoisted every major functionality and after that I've ended up with a huge Composable function:

**HomeScreen.kt**

```
TopSection(
                filterParametersState = filterParametersState,
                itineraryCount = flightsFromApiResponse.result?.itineraryCount ?: 0,
                buttonNames = viewModel.buttonNames,
                buttonNamesFilters = viewModel.buttonNamesFilters,
                selectedButtonIndex = viewModel.selectedButtonIndex.value,
                selectedButtonName = viewModel.selectedButtonName.value,
                isThemeSwitchChecked = themeViewModel.isDarkTheme,
                selectedSort = viewModel.selectedSort.value,
                updateSelectedSort = { sortName -> viewModel.updateSelectedSort(sortName) },
                getLocation = { cityName -> viewModel.getLocation(cityName) },
                updateFlightSearchDepartureTime = { date ->
                    viewModel.updateFlightSearchDepartureTime(
                        date = date
                    )
                },
                updateFlightSearchCityDeparture = {
                    viewModel.updateFlightSearchCityDeparture(
                        city = viewModel.location.value.cityCode ?: "WAR"
                    )
                },
                updateFlightSearchCityArrival = {
                    viewModel.updateFlightSearchCityArrival(
                        city = viewModel.location.value.cityCode ?: "PAR"
                    )
                },
                updateFlightSearchPassengersCount = { passengerCount ->
                    viewModel.updateFlightSearchPassengersCount(
                        passengers = passengerCount
                    )
                },
                onDisableNextDayArrivalsClicked = { isDisabled ->
                    viewModel.updateFilterDisableNextDayArrivals(
                        isDisabled
                    )
                },
                onDurationButtonClicked = { buttonName ->
                    viewModel.updateFilterMaxDuration(
                        buttonName
                    )
                },
                onThemeSwitchClicked = { themeViewModel.switchTheme() },
                onSliderValueChange = { valueFromSlider ->
                    viewModel.updateFilterMaxPrice(
                        valueFromSlider
                    )
                },
                onParamsUpperClicked = { buttonIndex, buttonName ->
                    viewModel.updateSelectedButtonIndex(buttonIndex)
                    viewModel.updateSelectedButtonName(buttonName)
                },
                onParamsBottomClicked = { buttonName ->
                    if (buttonName != "SAVE") {
                        viewModel.updateSelectedButtonName(buttonName)
                    } else {
                        commonViewModel.updateCurrentFlightParams(flightSearchParametersState)
                        viewModel.getFlights()
                    }
                }
            )
```

How can I avoid this? I know that technically I could separate **TopSection** into other smaller Composable functions, but in my case I feel like the apporach I've applied is appropriate. To be precise, **TopSection** is a section in **HomeScreen** in which I handle couple of small functionalities.

[image]

Comment: you can combine some of the parameters in a `data class` , through this your `composable` function will not look messy.

Comment: @JayantKumar Could you elaborate and provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can incapsulate your data in data class this way:

**In your ViewModel:**

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _buttonUiState = MutableStateFlow(ButtonUiState())
    val buttonUiState: StateFlow<ButtonUiState>
        get() = _buttonUiState.asStateFlow()
    
    fun setNewState(index: Int) {
        _buttonUiState.update { 
            it.copy(
                buttonIndex = index
            )
        }
    }
}

data class ButtonUiState(
    val buttonIndex: Int = 0,
    val buttonNames: List<String> = listOf()
    ...
)
```

And in your composable function you can collect buttonUiState this way:

```
@Composable
fun ParentComposable(
    viewModel: MyViewModel
) {
    val buttonUiState by viewModel.buttonUiState.collectAsState()
    TopSection(
        buttonUiState = buttonUiState
        ...
    )
}
```

**EDIT:**
Also see this [article](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events)

It describes the event interaction with ui, which makes easy to calling methods in ViewModel

Comment: OK, I get it. But one more thing - As you can see my TopSection function recieved arguments are mostly functions. Can i include a function in my data class as a parameter, and then implement it in the ViewModel?

Comment: @deja it makes no sense to declare functions as parameters in the data class, as you can directly create a function in ViewModel and call it from ui like this: viewModel.doSomething()

Comment: Ok. And if my ButtonUiState has parameters: selectedbuttonIndex and selectedButtonName, when I write update ui function, should I include both parameters update in one function, or rather seperate them in updateSelectedButtonIndex() and updateSelectedButtonName()?

Comment: @deja if you need to change only one parameter then you can update UiState with update { copy(param=value) }. no need to pass two parameters if you need update only one. For the copy function to work as in the example in UiState you need to add default value: data class(val data: Int = 0)

Comment: I've implemented your solution and it works perfectly fine, however my TopSection function is still really big due to the functions I'm passing to it: (updateFlightSearchDepartureCity(), updateFlightSearchArrivalCity() etc.) Can I pack it further more to reduce the space it takes, or should I just simply leave it as it is?

Comment: @deja It is normal for functions like updateFlightSearchDepartureCity. In android/nowinandroid github repository they do same. In their code some functions have ten parameters or more

Answer (score 0):

First make `data class or normal class` and add some parameters

```
data class SomeContent(
 ...
 ...
)
```

after that pass this data class in `TopSection` composable function

```
 TopSection(
     someContent:SomeContent
    ){
....
....
    }
```

you can also take reference from `Text` composable function , where it takes `TextStyle` as a parameter for `color , font , fontWeight etc` and it's a `class`

```
Text(text = "Hey", style = TextStyle(
        color = Color.Red,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        fontSize = 20.sp
    ))
```

Hope you understood this thing.

Comment: what I don't understand is how to store these functions in this data class?